# Error when migrate my pods to Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: xcode, migration, swift4

I'm trying to migrate my project to xcode 10.2.1, but first I need to migrate my code to swift 4. My project was migrated to swift 4 without problems, but after I try to update the pods file to swift 4 running pod update, the RSBarcodes_swift start to show an error below.

Pods/RSBarcodes_Swift/Source/RSUnifiedCodeGenerator.swift:33:74: Expression pattern of type 'AVMetadataObject.ObjectType' cannot match values of type 'String'

Does anyone already face this issue?

Comment: Did you update the pod to which version? A compatible one with Swift 4?

Comment: I just run pod update, the minimum version is set for 3